# Calculating the starting size of a length, when it grows per iteration and must remain within a limit

Tags: c#, math, recursion, formula, fractals

Ok so, obviously from the way I've worded my question; I'm no mathematician. I'm currently experimenting with fractals, and this specific question refers to the 'TSqare' fractal. (See bottom of question for explanation).

Basically I want to calculate the size of the initial square, so the resulting fractal of depth(n) never extends beyond the limit of the drawing surface. I've tried to figure it out myself, but I'm getting no where.

All I have figured out is the rate the square grows:

> Assuming an initial size of 100, total length of fractal is as follows
>   Depth(0) = 100
>   Depth(1) = 150
>   Depth(2) = 175

<strike>Unfortunately I can't even figure out the formula for that, even though the pattern is obvious. D:</strike>

length = originalLength + (originalLength / 2 ^ depth)

So I've bubbled this down to algebra, assuming the drawing surface is 512 * 512, and the current depth is 2. The formula is as follows:

x + (x / 2<sup>2</sup>) = 512

Then all I need to do is solve for x right to get the initial size for depth size 2?

TSquare Definition: An initial square S<sub>0</sub> is drawn with size x<sup>2</sup>. Each iteration 4 Squares half the size of the original (x<sup>2</sup>/2) are drawn with their centers on the 4 vertices of the square before it. See http://www.smokycogs.com/blog/t-square-fractals/ for more details.

Comment: NB: Currently my drawing surface is 512px * 512px and I'm hard coding the initial size at 280. The fractal extends beyond the drawing surface at D(4)

Comment: Did you figure out the answer to your question? You seem to imply that you did in your edit comment. If you did solve it, you should probably say so in the question (or answer your question), because most people aren't going to read your edit comment probably.

Comment: Not quite, I know the algebraic function, but I have no idea how to implement it D:. (I know the formula for growth, but don't know how to rearrange the function).

Comment: x = 409.6 for the case you put in your question, or `x = 512 * 2^d/(2^d + 1)` for any `d`, where `d` equals the `depth` and `x` equals the initial size.

Comment: You sir are a legend. If you could post that equation as an answer, I would love to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the original length for any depth, where the max size equals the originalLength + (originalLength / 2 ^ depth), you can set up the equation `m = x + (x/2^d)`. Solving this for `x`, you get `x = m * 2^d/(2^d + 1)` for any `d`, where `d` equals the `depth`, `x` equals the `initial size`, and `m` equals the `maximum size` (512 in your case). So, for your question of what's the initial size if the depth equals 2 and the max size = 512, the initial size is `409.6`.

For future reference, a better place to ask this probably would've been https://math.stackexchange.com/. (Since this question's a little more about math and equations that programming).

HTH